# How to decode in laravel join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

> I have json resource collection like this

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\Curriculum;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CurriculumDisplayResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
 
        return [

                      'id' => $this->id,
                      'title_section' => json_decode($this->title_section),
                      'learning_objective'=> json_decode($this->learning_objective),
                      'content_detail' =>

                          DB::table('curriculums')
                              ->join('content_texts','curriculums.id','=','content_texts.curriculum_id')
                              ->join('content_files','curriculums.id','=','content_files.curriculum_id')
                              ->join('content_videos','curriculums.id','=','content_videos.curriculum_id')
                              ->join('quizzes','curriculums.id','=','quizzes.curriculum_id')
                              ->select('content_texts.title_text','content_texts.text_course',
                                  'content_files.title_file','content_files.file_course','content_videos.title_video',
                                  'content_videos.video_course','quizzes.title_quiz','quizzes.question','quizzes.answer','quizzes.right_answer')
                              ->get(),

                      'parent_id' => $this->id,
                  ];
    }
}
```

Can I json decode the result of join quiz?, I just want to json decode the quizzes result. when I'm try display this json resource the result like this

[image]

> this is the controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Course;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\CurriculumResource;
use App\Models\Curriculum;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Curriculum::all();
    }

    public function store (Request $request)
    {

        $c = new Curriculum();
        $c->title_section = json_encode($request->get('title_section'));
        $c->learning_objective = json_encode($request->get('learning_objective'));
        $c->user_id = Auth::id();
        $c->course_id = $request->get('course_id');



        $c->save();

        return response(new CurriculumResource($c));

    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?, I've also made cast for title_quiz, question, answer and right_answer.

Comment: you can use `->toArray()` after get function, no need to use `json_Decode()`.

Comment: not changed at all, still the same

Comment: please share your code and the response.

Comment: i have updated the tread

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help your problem. It seems like you have double quotation mark

On your Model which has title_quiz, question, answer, and right_answer, add this line of code (depend on your Model):

**Model.php**

```
public function getTitleQuizAttribute($value){
    return str_replace('\"','', $value);
}


public function getQuestionAttribute($value){
    return str_replace('\"','', $value);
}


public function getRightAnswerAttribute($value){
    return str_replace('\"','', $value);
}


public function title_quiz($value){
    return str_replace('\"','', $value);
}


public function getAnswerAttribute($value){
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

They will modify your string first then pass it to your response

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: and in controller I wrote it like this   $quiz->title_quiz = (new \App\Models\Quiz)->title_quiz($request->title_quiz); ?

Comment: Dont edit anything on controller, the Accessor (that public function stuff) just modify your data first then show it on your response